# How can we send message by pressing enter in a chat window using splinter?

Tags: python, automation, splinter

In a chat window ( watsapp, facebook etc. ) message can be sent by pressing "Enter", How can we achieve that in splinter. I tried submitting the form using `browser.execute_script()` but its reloading the full page instead.

Also tried `browser.get_by_id("id_name").type("something \r")` but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting everything finally this code worked for me:

```
from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser()
script = 'var event = jQuery.Event("keydown"); event.which = 13; event.keyCode = 13; $("#element_id").trigger(event);'
browser.execute_script(script)
```

I found that some people are using `jQuery.Event("keypress")` but it didn't worked for me.